Approximation for the derivative of the covariance matrix for unknown points in Gaussian Proccesses
I hope the title is descriptive enough and I feel a bit stupid right now. During a derivation of mine concerning derivatives, the following term popped up
$$
K_{x*,x}K^{-1}_{xx} \frac{\partial K_{xx}}{\partial q} K^{-1}_{xx} K_{x,x*}
$$
where $x$ are the training points and $x*$ unknown points and $q$ a coordinate the point depends on. $K$ is the co-variance matrix. My gut tells me that this expression is at least in least-square fit sense an approximation to
$$
\frac{\partial K_{x*x*}}{\partial q}
$$
But right now I'm not able to show this. Maybe I just want it to be true since it would simplify the final expression in my derivation.
Any thoughts are welcome. Maybe I'm on the wrong track.
